# Need to Update Solr Api field using unique selector

Tags: node.js, reactjs, solr, axios

I am using the below code.

Need to Update Status field Using Unique Key Value.. But Nothing happens.

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: configured
    }
}

axios.patch('https://localhost:8983/solr/issue/', {key: 'INC0265740', status: 'open'},
    config).then(function(response) {
    //var issuesnew = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    logger.error('Tickets Failed Because of' + error);
});
```

Comment: could you please explain what you want to do, and what you need and what's your error?

Comment: in the above solr api i have two columns key will be the unique id .. using the key value i need to update status column.

Comment: Does Solr even support using `PATCH`? Solr expects a request to the /update endpoint, usually  .. with JSON attached.

Comment: I tried using Post too but its not working